# Can only read 0 from ioremap() memory

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, xilinx, spi, ioremap

I am developing a simple driver for linux that will talk to a device over SPI.
After i use request_mem_region and ioremap all i can read from the returned address is 0
even after i write a value to it. The address at offset 0 should be the control register for the SPI controller (it is a Xilinx Zynq SoC). The control register is set with a initial value during the the boot process.

Code:

```
int device_init() {
    int ret;
    ret = register_chrdev(device_major, DEVICE_NAME, &fops);
    if(ret < 0) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "spi: cannot obtain major number %d.\n", device_major);
        return ret;
    }

    if(request_mem_region (SPI_ADDR, SPI_SIZE, "SPI Driver") == NULL)
    {
        printk("Failed to request memory region!\n");
        device_exit();
        return 1;
    }
    spi = ioremap(SPI_ADDR, SPI_SIZE);
    if(spi == NULL)
    {
        printk("I/O remap failed\n");
        device_exit();
        return 1;
    }

    printk("Driver init complete. Mapped to address 0x%X\n", spi);
    iowrite32be(0x20000, spi);
    printk("%X\n", ioread32be(spi));
    return 0;
}
```

The output when i insert the module is:
Driver init complete. Mapped to address 0xE08C2000
0

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your question is not too clear..!!! Will you elaborate more that what you want to ask after `ioremap` step in the above code..!!!!

Comment: @jhonnash What i want to do after i use ioremap() is to read and write to/from the location that is mapped (physical address 0xE0007000 - 0xE0007FFF). The first 4 bytes should have a value that was set during boot, but i read only 0 from that location, even if i write to it using iowrite32 first and then try to read it using ioread32.

Comment: Have you verified that you can write to that register using a Standalone application or XMD?

Comment: Yes I have a bare metal application working, I also have it working using mmap on /dev/mem from userspace.

Comment: You should be using `ioremap_nocache()` since your writing directly to a device here.  Also I believe that Xilinx devices for the most part are big endian, so you may have to use iowrite32be().  Can you also humor me and put an iowrite32() statement before the printk() statements to write to the spi port and then attach to the question here the last few lines from dmesg after loading the driver?

Comment: I have now updated the question with the information you asked @BenjaminLeinweber. I have tried with both regular and big endian versions of the functions, I still only read 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be it so I'm putting it in an answer.  I'm familiar with Xilinx in general but not with the SPI core specifically.  I just had a look at the [Xilinx SPI core data sheet](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/xps_spi.pdf).  The Table 4 on page 8 has a summary of the registers.  There are no registers at the base address.  I'm not sure why the core responds to the base address at all, but maybe it's hard coded to 0.

Anyways, after the `ioremap()` try this:

```
void *ipier;

ipier = spi + 0x28;
printk("Driver init complete. Mapped to address 0x%X\n", spi);
iowrite32be(0x20000, ipier);
printk("%X\n", ioread32be(ipier));
```

This is of course assuming that the IPIER register isn't removed from the IP core due to some sort of setting, of course.

---

Edit:
Per the Op's comment below, the Op is not using the SPI IP Core, so this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that is not the SPI Controller i am using. I am using the SPI controller integrated in the Zync XC7Z020 SoC register overview can be found here: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf on page 1660. The register at offset 0 should be the config register.

Comment: That's what I get for answering questions on hardware I've not used before.  Unfortunately, I didn't see endianess referred to in this document, so I can't be certain that the Zynq actually is big endian or little endian.  Looks like you're trying to set bit 17, which I see is a valid bit.  Even if the endianess was backwards, it would be bit 9, which is also a valid bit.  I'm afraid that I'm not going to be of any help on this one.  Everything looks fine from my point of view.